# Calculating rank and awards from MySQL database on a rating website

Tags: php, mysql, ranking, rating

I have a rating website where people can "award" people certain awards: "Cutest", "Awesomest", "I Like you", "Hottest", "Prettiest", "Funniest", etc and negative ones like "Lamest", "Stupidest", "I Hate you", etc.

When someone adds a new person using my rate page, it is stored in a table with these columns: from,to,award. So for example if my userid is 5, and the person I am giving the award "cutest" is 10, then it is stored like this: 5,10,cutest.

Now the thing is, I want to give people ranks, firstly, based on each award.. Like the person who got the most "cutest" awards.. and then, based overall, like the person who got the most positive awards. For the overall, people should downrank if they have many negative awards, and uprank for positive awards.

I cannot (because of the way my script is coded) have another table for counts like: id,award,count (which could be 10,lamest,20, which would mean user id 10, and 20 lamest awards given).. So how do I calculate it? an efficient way, in PHP.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Please think over what you said regarding "cannot (because of the way my script is coded)". I'm sure you'll find out you can do just that. Just each time, before inserting a new line, just update the existing line, if such exists...

Comment: Yes, I know it would be possible if I majorly edit the code..But these awards need to be calculated only on a weekly or monthly basis (via cron jobs or even manually) so if it IS possible, then it would be nice if I can do it with the current table structure..!

Comment: Hmm well in that case, you can request for example all the "cutest" reviews, and then iterate through the results and keep for each ID you see a counter in an array of counters and update his count. You get what I'm saying?

Comment: Update: I've set a cron to do that every week, and it updates a seperate table which stores the top awardee of each category.

Off-topic: Can you suggest some Award categories for me? Like Most Liked, Most Hated, Hottest, Cutest, Funniest, Awesomest, etc :D?